# Why, Elements inside <td> tag height isn't increasing?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to increase the height of elements inside `<td>` tag. However, the Height isn't increasing.

More specifically, I want the `<p>` tag inside `<td>` tag with 100% height.

The Code Is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>
    <!-- Local CSS -->
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        table {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        td {
            background-color: aqua;
        }

        input {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        p {
            background-color: blueviolet;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2"><input type="text" name="console" id="Console"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p onclick="one()">1</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p  onclick="two()">2</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: height:100% requires an height set on parent else it is xx% of nothing equals null :( . Do you really need a table here ? would flex or grid be fine ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus actually his code works fine In chrome. Only failing in Firefox

Comment: @TemaniAfif ff once did it too, not sure which one is right about this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need set to `display: inline-table;` or `display: table;`. And  `margin: 0px;` becose this is a `p` tag and this tag by default have a margin value

Replace `p` style in your CSS with this one
:

```
p {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    display: inline-table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

**Preview:**

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

table {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    background-color: aqua;
}

input {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    display: inline-table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"><input type="text" name="console" id="Console"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td onclick="one()">
            <p>1</p>
        </td>
        <td onclick="two()">
            <p>2</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

while waiting for a feed back on my comment, here is a grid layout  example that does what you want without specifying `height` for `p` being direct children of a `grid`.

It also mimics a `table-layout` without side effects and extra markup.

```css
html,
body,
.border {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.border,
.border p {
  border: solid;
  padding: 2px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
 grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr ;  /* optionnal, here you can set heights for the rows */
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

p:first-of-type {
  grid-column: span 2;
  padding:0;
}

p {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid border">
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="console" id="Console">
  </p>
  <p onclick="one()">1</p>
  <p onclick="two()">2</p>
</div>
```

---

this might be useful to you : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/  &  https://gridbyexample.com/ to start with ;)